# UK supplier of short toe clips for small footed woman

Tags: toe-straps-clips

My wife has size 4 feet and we are struggling to find a comfortable set of toeclips for her.

At the moment, even the Zefal 043 "medium" clips are too long, leaving her with her feet almost centred on the pedal.

We are looking for a set of strapped, two-pronged toe clips, ideally nylon, but which have a shorter than normal plate. Does anyone know of a such a product and where it can be obtained in the UK?

(Clipless pedals are not under consideration....)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This doesn't technically answer your question, but you might consider [Power Grips](http://www.mountainracingproducts.com/power-grips/). If they're too big, you can take them to a leather worker and have a couple extra holes punched in them so that you can tighten them down farther.

Answer (score 1):

MKS, while alloy, makes smaller toe clips. I personally have a set of their small toe clips as I wanted to reduce toe overlap.

http://www.mkspedal.com/English/MKS_padal_news.htm

Most places that distribute MKS toe clips can order you the XS or Small size.